# Using Select *, in Oracle (PL/SQL)

Tags: plsql, ssis, sysdate

I am trying to do this in an SSIS task that is connected to an Oracle table:

```
Select *, SYSDATE  from OracleTable1
```

And Oracle doesn't like it, saying the 'from keyword not found where expected'.  Interestingly this would run fine if connected to a SQL source.  Also interestingly if I entered the columns to replace the * it also runs.  So what is it about oracle that doesn't allow the '*, sysdate'?

Am I just doing something wrong?  I want ALL columns regardless, then a sysdate.  Why is that not possible?  I just want to avoid listing columns (that could be renamed upstream) and break the job.  I'd rather have nulls than a error'd job.  To put it in perspective, I would rather the reports that the data feeds have one or two null fields as opposed to nothing in the reports at all.

Comment: I'd simply try `Select ot1.*, SYSDATE AS sd FROM OracleTable1 ot1` providing an table alias and an output column name for your SYSDATE.

Comment: Wouldn't your job break anyway if a source column gets renamed or removed?

Comment: No it would just not map that column, and then that column would be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select OracleTable1.*, SYSDATE  from OracleTable1
```

It should work when qualified with the table/alias

Comment: Thank you!  I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.